# React-native not able to uninstall react-native-maps

Tags: react-native-maps

Receiving following error when try to uninstall

$ npm uninstall --save react-native-maps/
npm WARN react-dom@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.44.0 requires a peer of react@16.0.0-alpha.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-elements@0.9.7 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@~4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.13.0 requires a peer of react@>=15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native@0.41.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-windows@0.41.0-rc.0 requires a peer of react-native@~0.41.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-windows@0.41.0-rc.0 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-static-container@1.0.1 requires a peer of react@^0.13.0 || ^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-test-renderer@15.4.2 requires a peer of react@^15.4.2 but none was installed.

Can someone tell, how to resolve these warnings and uninstall react-native-maps?

Comment: npm uninstall <name> --save also remove from dependencies in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `react` and `react-native` modules installed. The message format `WARN react-dom@15.5.4 requires a peer of react@^15.5.4 but none was installed.` tells you that `react-dom` needs `react` but `react` is not present.

You also need to make sure you install the proper version of `react` and `react-native`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
react-native unlink react-native-maps && yarn remove react-native-maps.It will remove all the related packages in android & ios folder also.